# Best practices for formatting a message for MessageBox.Show(...) in Winforms for Vista

Tags: winforms, windows-vista, messagebox

In XP/2003 I had become accustomed to writing my `MessageBox.Show(..)` code like this :

```
MessageBox.Show("Title", "Sorry an error has occured!\n" +
                         "You may want to try one of the following:\n\n" +
                         "1. Reboot your machine\n" +  
                         "2. Buy a new machine\n" +  
                         "3. Report your error on StackOverflow.com.\n");
```

i.e. I formatted the message nicely and readable. If I didnt then it would fill the whole width of the screen and was not very friendly.

Now when the same message box comes up in Vista it is formatted completely differently and it introduces its own linefeeds and generally looks a lot worse.

What is the best practice for this for an application for both Vista and XP - short of writing my own message box class.

What are others doing to overcome this problem

Answer (score 3):

Just a remark, but in Vista, is not a [TaskDialog](http://shellrevealed.com/blogs/shellblog/archive/2006/09/19/So-long-MessageBox-and-thanks-for-all-the-memories.aspx) more appropriate for this kind of dialog ?

[alt text http://shellrevealed.com/photos/blog_images/images/659/411x278.aspx](http://shellrevealed.com/photos/blog_images/images/659/411x278.aspx)

Otherwise, this [thread](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?referrerid=61394&t=541505) does mention a way to insert newlines in a Messagebox.

```
MessageBox.Show( "This" & Environment.NewLine & "is" & Environment.NewLine & "a test",
                 "Lines", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)
```

See [Environment.Newline property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)